# How do I put the table number and caption on separate lines?

Tags: captions

I have a table like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{AUC Interpretation}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}}                                                       
& \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Interpretation\end{tabular}}  \\ 
\midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}.50\end{tabular} & Chance   \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}.70\end{tabular} & Acceptable \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}.75\end{tabular} & Large      \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}.80\end{tabular} & Excellent  \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}.90 and higher\end{tabular} & Outstanding               
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I.e., 
[image]

How would I get the title and Table number to be on separate lines like this: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package for that.  The nested tabulars are not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  textfont=it,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{AUC Interpretation}
  \label{tab:auc-interpretation}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} & \textbf{Interpretation} \\
    \midrule
    .50                              & Chance                  \\
    \midrule
    .70                              & Acceptable              \\
    \midrule
    .75                              & Large                   \\
    \midrule
    .80                              & Excellent               \\
    \midrule
    .90 and higher                   & Outstanding             \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]